# Date format including time

Tags: formatage, dates

What is the correct date format that includes the time, name of day, day of the month and year?

I tried searching online for an answer, but a lot of sites do it very differently.

For now, I'm using "11:21:32, lundi, le 22 décembre 2014" format, but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Comment: Whatever you choose to do with the rest of it, if you do use the "le," be sure to follow M42's answer below and correctly put it before "lundi" and not before "22".   

I'm not sure who started the unfortunate myth that "le lundi" "sounds weird and is therefore always wrong," but it has rapidly gone from "unfortunate myth" to "absolute truth" in many French classes taught here where I live.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, the format used for date time in french is:

> le lundi 22 décembre 2014 à 11:21:32

or:

> le lundi 22 décembre 2014 à 11h21min

or:

> lundi 22 décembre 2014 à 11h21

Comment: Pour une date qui n'est pas incluse dans un texte, on peut supprimer le *le* et remplacer le *à* par un  **-** : `lundi 22 décembre 2014 - 15h45` ou `lundi 22 décembre 2014 - 15;45:35` si l'on affiche les secondes

Comment: I'm using it on a website that shows the **live** current date that includes the time (updated by seconds). So I don't think this format will do. I don't know French very well, but I think your format says "Monday, 22 December, 2014 at 11:21:32", that would be kind of odd?

Comment: @KidDiamond: That isn't odd at all, it's the way to write date + time in french.

Comment: I think this format is meant for in textual context right? @cl-r format is probably what I need. It's not referring to a certain point in time, but more general. If that makes sense. lol

Comment: @KidDiamond: Yes, it is. As said by cl-r in previous comment, you can remove the `le` if you're using the date/time alone.

Comment: “11h21” is also much more natural than “11h21mn”.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais lu “mn”…

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez C'était pourtant l'abréviation officielle de minute jusqu'en 1975.

Comment: @jlliagre: pour une durée c'est vrai, je l'ai rencontré, mais pas pour l'heure.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Ça n'était pas clair alors. Cette remarque semblait concerner l'abréviation « mn » qui à d'ailleurs été mise à jour ensuite, pas la présence de minutes qui est effectivement rare puisqu'on ne dit que très rarement « minutes » à l'oral, sauf si les secondes sont aussi présentes.