# Liter/100 km or km/Liter

Tags: usage, france, unités

In America we say the fuel economy of car as miles/gallon (miles per gallon). I know in some countries people use Liter/100 km (liter per 100 km). Some countries use km/Liter (km per liter).

My question is: which format French people use?

L/100 km or km/L?

Comment: I just looked on the French web sites of Toyota, Honda, and Citroën, and they all use L/100km. Except for the electric models which use €/100km.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about the French language.

Comment: This is not a language question. If you speak French and you live in the US, you will talk about miles/gallon, even though you'd talk about liters/100 km in France, because that's the unit used, not because you speak French or English.

Comment: IMO, this question is not asking whether French people use gallons or liters when discussing fuel economy/consumption, but rather which format is used (i.e., does one mention first the distance traveled or does one mention first the amount of fuel consumed?) (Also, I interpret “French people use” to mean “used in France”) Therefore, I don’t see this question being any more off-topic/worthy of closure than [this {+6} one](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12644/) about date/time formatting, which doesn’t even specify that it's limited to  “French people” or “in France.” (regardless, +1)

Comment: @Kareen: I agree with Papa Poule, I think this is the kind of question we can answer, since it is easy to answer, and difficult to know for strangers... (you can't find this kind of stuff in a dictionnary...)

Comment: You can also find the indication of the price per kilometer in some articles but the information is valuable for a short period of time (when you read the article) since the price for a litter of gasoline is always fluctuating.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The unit mostly used is liters per 100kms ([Consommation de carburant par les voitures](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consommation_de_carburant_par_les_voitures)). In day-to-day life, it's pronounced “litres aux cent” (short for “litres aux cent kilomètres”).

Comment: I would say exclusively instead of mostly, at least in France.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.